# Thorough though Thoreau threw, Troll throws through tough troughs

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

To each of these nine [confusingly similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation) words, assign a number 1-9 in any way you like:

```
though
through
thorough
Thoreau
throw
threw
trough
tough
troll
```

Write a program that takes in a string. If the input is one of these nine words, output the number you assigned to it. If the input is not one of the words above, the program may do anything (including error or loop forever).

The words are case sensitive, e.g. `Thoreau`, should produce a number from 1-9 but `thoreau` will not necessarily do the same.

### Example

Suppose you assign the numbers as follows:

```
though   9
through  2
thorough 7
Thoreau  6
throw    3
threw    5
trough   4
tough    1
troll    8
```

Then when `tough` is input, `1` should be output.
When `through` is input, `2` should be output.
When `throw` is input, `3` should be output.
. . .
When `though` is input, `9` should be output.

All other inputs may do anything.

### Details

- Take the input string via stdin or the command line and output to stdout.
- The output may contain a single trailing newline.
- Instead of a program, you may write a function that takes in a string and prints the result normally or returns it.
- **The shortest submission in bytes wins[.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjzyAHKYJ8M&feature=youtu.be&t=22s)**

Comment: Darn it! I had a clever solution to output zero when not found by using the Python string `find` method. Then the rules changed. Clever idea not so clever now.

Comment: @CarpetPython My bad really. Don't hesitate to downvote if you feel unsatisfied with the change. (Though I promise to everyone there will be no more changes.)

Comment: That's ok. I think my answer is still valid (though I little verbose).

Comment: Can I make it work regardless of capitalization?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI as long as it works for the 9 cases

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## CJam, <s>11 9</s> 7 bytes

```
q1b2+B%
```

**How it works**:

We are making use of the fact that the sum of the ASCII codes + 2 moded with 11 gives very nice order of 1 through 9 and then 10 for the nine concerned words. Here is the ordering:

```
through -> 1
thorough -> 2 
tough -> 3 
Thoreau -> 4 
throw -> 5 
threw -> 6 
trough -> 7 
though -> 8 
troll -> 9
```

**Code explanation**:

```
q               e# Read the input
 1b             e# Sum the ASCII code values of all characters in this word
   2+           e# Increment the sum by 2
     B%         e# Mod by 11 and automatically print the mod result at the end
```

*4 bytes saved thanks to user23013*

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q1bB%25)9e%3C&input=thorough)

Comment: How are we supposed to try it? (not everyone speaks CJam, some of us speak lolcode)

Comment: @Behrooz There is a link. Click on it, put your input in the input section, Run. Not sure how it can be easier :)

Comment: Holly shit, I was thinking how am I supposed to give it the list of words. nice one

Comment: `:i:+` is the same as `1b`.

Comment: @user23013 Damn! Every single time!

Comment: In fact it's probably because I'm currently not posting so many answers. And if my answer is longer (sometimes much longer) than existing answers, I choose not to post in most cases.

Comment: Looking at the link: it should work, but it does not. Just a CJAM empty box, no code, no input. In Firefox.

Comment: @edc65 some known issues with firefox. Try opening the link in chrome

Comment: Or ``q1b2+B%``.

Comment: `ÇOÌ11%` - 05AB1E, your method, 6 bytes.

Answer (score 18):

## Pyth, 8 chars

```
e%Cz8109
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e%25Cz8109&input=thorough&debug=0) or [Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=zFz.zp%22%20%3D%3E%20%22ze%25Cz8109&input=%22Test%20Cases%22%0Athough%0Athrough%0Athorough%0AThoreau%0Athrow%0Athrew%0Atrough%0Atough%0Atroll&debug=0)

I'm using the assignment:

```
though   5
through  9
thorough 4
Thoreau  7
throw    3
threw    2
trough   8
tough    6
troll    1
```

#### Explanation:

```
   z       input()
  C        convert to int (convert each char to their ASCII value
           and interprete the result as number in base 256)
 %  8109   modulo 8109
e          modulo 10
```

Btw, I found the magic number 8109 by using this script: [`fqr1 10Sme%CdT.z1`](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqr1+10Sme%25CdT.z1&input=though%0Athrough%0Athorough%0AThoreau%0Athrow%0Athrew%0Atrough%0Atough%0Atroll&debug=0).

Comment: Will this not have false-positives?

Comment: @alexander-brett What exactly do you mean? The output of all other inputs is not specified in the OP. We can output anything we want.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that edit to the OP. That's a shame :P

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2, <s>92</s> 54 bytes

```python
print'K{7j)yE<}'.find(chr(hash(raw_input())%95+32))+1
```

The index string is created with `for word in words: print chr(hash(word)%95+32),`. As pointed out in Jakube's answer, the hash function will give different results depending on Python version. This index string is computed on 64 bit Python 2.7.6.

Longer (92 bytes) but less cryptic answer:

```python
print'though through thorough Thoreau throw threw trough tough troll'.find(raw_input())/7+1
```

The programs returns 1-9 for *though through thorough Thoreau throw threw trough tough troll* in that order. When the input is not found, find will return a -1 which conveniently turns into a zero after the `+1`.

Comment: Note that the `0` stuff is no longer required. Sorry for changing it on you.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the effort. It was a good solution for a little while...

Comment: @CarpetPython Nice use of floor-division -- it works out surprisingly neatly.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2.7.9 32 bit version, 22 bytes

```
lambda x:hash(x)%78%10
```

Notice, the version is really important here. You will get different results if your using a 64 bit version of Python. Since the `hash` method will compute 64 bit hash values instead of 32 bit.

The assignment is:

```
though  => 5   through => 6   thorough => 8
Thoreau => 7   throw   => 3   threw    => 1
trough  => 9   tough   => 4   troll    => 2
```

Try it online: http://ideone.com/Rqp9J8

Comment: Wow, so all this time, you were iterating through language versions and operating system bits ? :P

Comment: Very nice answer. Did you find the constant 78 through mathematics, automated iteration, or some guesses?

Comment: @CarpetPython Just a simple brute-force loop which goes through all possible modules. Once `sorted(...)==range(1,10)`, I stopped.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
et%Cz31
```

I am using the following asignment:

```
though   8
through  3
thorough 1
Thoreau  5
throw    4
threw    7
trough   6
tough    2
troll    9
```

`Cz` interprets the input as a base 256 number. Then, we take this mod 31, subtract 1, and take the result mod 10. Equivalent pseudocode:

```
((base_256(input()) % 31) - 1) % 10
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=et%25Cz31&input=Thoreau&debug=0), [test harness](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Fz%2Bz.zet%25Cz31&input=though%0Athrough%0Athorough%0AThoreau%0Athrow%0Athrew%0Atrough%0Atough%0Atroll&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
nH %BÉ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bkggJULJ&input=InRob3VnaCI) | [Test all words](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bkggJULJ&footer=VmdXKfo5ICsiPSAiK1U&input=WwoidGhvdWdoIgoidGhyb3VnaCIKInRob3JvdWdoIgoiVGhvcmVhdSIKInRocm93IgoidGhyZXciCiJ0cm91Z2giCiJ0b3VnaCIKInRyb2xsIgpdLW1S)

---

### Explanation

Takes advantage of the fact that, when parsing a base-`n` string to an integer, JavaScript will stop parsing if it encounters a digit greater than `n` and return the result up to that point. By using base-32 here (digits `0-v`) the `w`s in "threw" and "throw" are, essentially, ignored.

```
nH      :Convert from base-32
   %B   :Modulo 11
     É  :Subtract 1
```

Here's a breakdown of the formula applied to each word:

| Input | `nH` | `%B` | `É` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| through | 31738067473 | 2 | 1 |
| tough | 31226385 | 3 | 2 |
| troll | 31318709 | 4 | 3 |
| trough | 1002207761 | 5 | 4 |
| though | 991722001 | 6 | 5 |
| thro*w* | 968568 | 7 | 6 |
| thre*w* | 968558 | 8 | 7 |
| thorough | 1015520459281 | 9 | 8 |
| Thoreau | 31735003486 | 10 | 9 |

---

### JavaScript, 22 bytes

A direct translation - doesn't seem worth posting it separately.

```js
f=
U=>parseInt(U,32)%11-1
o.innerText=["through","tough","troll","trough","though","throw","threw","thorough","Thoreau"].map(s=>f(s)+": "+s).join`\n`
```

```html
<pre id=o><pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
C∑⇧11%
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=C%E2%88%91%E2%87%A711%25&inputs=threw&header=&footer=)

Cjam port.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 27 bytes

```
f=lambda w:int(w,34)%444/46
```

With this assignment:

```
>>> for w in "though through thorough Thoreau throw threw trough tough troll".split(): print f(w),w
...
9 though
7 through
3 thorough
8 Thoreau
2 throw
5 threw
6 trough
1 tough
4 troll
```

Several variations are possible, e.g.

```
f=lambda w:int(w,35)/159%10
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 66 bytes

```c
h,k;f(char*s){for(h=33;*s;)h^=*s++;h=strchr(k="(Z5qW]2@H",h)-k+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7LasMwEEXX0lcMAoNkKZAHWbSKoMt@QKGQxAEjxxljx2olhyyMv91RHs7qHLiXmWtnJ2vHEVWtS24x92kQfek8R7Na6TRogQeTBik1mtB5i57XhvHt@v83W359M4ViVsuFHsaq7eCcVy0XtKfkfgrSq/NF2GWmZx26ywmZiuLf5ib9iXrML6/4@uTxwXd7ondNwwZNCSVxJ/D73woMzHXEBj4ipBSUkD8fo5KzJHxCUuxbpuC5p8oUlHxyITQdxhs)

Comment: May require the `-O` compiler flag. `h;f(char*s){for(h=33;*s;)h^=*s++;h=index("(Z5qW]2@H",h)-"H"+9;}`

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>53</s> 25 bytes

```java
s->(s.chars().sum()+2)%11
```

or

```java
s->-~-~s.chars().sum()%11
```

Port of *@Optimizer*'s CJam answer, because it (most likely) cannot be done any shorter in Java..

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jc@xDsIgEAbgvU9xaWICMZLUtdE3sItuxuFEtCiFhgONMX32itrZkMDA3cf9cMU7Llyv7PV0G6VBItigtq8CQNug/BmlguZz/BZAsm3w2l6AeJ2KQ9ppUcCgJTRgYQUjLdaMhGzRE@OCYsf4fMlnVTXWP97Ho0l8unV3@gRdCp1G7w/If4HbJwXVCReD6FMnGMuskKwMrXfx0pb8@4Z/zmXCLLVL4xTGjFjvHjlKZajsn2Yx74yZ1FAM4xs)

Comment: Java has `parseInt`, doesn't it? Would a port of [my solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154456/58974) not be shorter?

Comment: @Shaggy Java indeed has `parseInt` with given base, but unfortunately it's quite byte-excessive due to static class requirement: `Long.parseLong(...,32)` as shortest variant. In addition, [it seems to fail for `"throw"` (and `"threw"` as well) in Java for some reason](https://tinyurl.com/y8c5lknu). `w` is outside the base-32 range it seems (and using 33 gives incorrect results).

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
OS+2%11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98/WNtI1dDw////SiUZRfml6RlKAA)

Boring Jelly port of the fantastic CJam answer.